# Infinity loop for React Bootstrap components

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I installed react-bootstrap 5.1.3 and the app functions normally, but when I copy and paste this component, the app enters an infinite loop. The terminal application runs fine, but the browser displays no errors. There are no additional components in my application.

React Version: 17.0.2

=> Navigation.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Navbar, NavDropdown } from "react-bootstrap";

const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
                Another action
              </NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Divider />
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">
                Separated link
              </NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
          <Nav>
            <Nav.Link href="#deets">More deets</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="#memes">
              Dank memes
            </Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

=> App.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import React from 'react';
import Nav from './components/Header/Nav';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Nav />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the name of your `Nav` component. You are trying to render `Nav` of **react-bootstrap** inside your Nav component but you did not import it from **react-bootstrap**. As a result, `Nav` calls itself and causes an infinite loop.

You should import `Nav` from **react-bootstrap** the name of your `Nav` function and its export command like:

```
import { Nav, Container, Navbar, NavDropdown } from "react-bootstrap";

const Navivation = () => {

// ...
};
export default Navivation;
```

you can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-hofstadter-o372p?file=/src/Nav.js) for a live working example.